# Why is the ground of the component, SP1050-04BTG, connected to the Power Supply of POE?

Tags: ethernet, surge-protection, poe

[image]

The SP1050-04BTG is a surge protector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out that having a zener diode in parallel to power supply will protect the power supply; the zener diode is simply clamping the voltage down.